# If statement for current date

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an `ElseIf` statement and the systems date to create an output.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim dateToday As Date
Dim fifth As Integer
Dim fifthteenth As Integer
Dim twentyEighth As Integer
Dim thirtieth As Integer

dateToday = Today
fifth = 5
fifthteenth = 17 'this is changed to todays date for testing otherwise its 15
twentyEighth = 28
thirtieth = 30

If fifth = dateToday Then
    MsgBox ("Today is the fifth")
ElseIf fifthteenth = dateToday Then
    MsgBox ("Today is the fifthteenth")
ElseIf twentyEighth = dateToday Then
    MsgBox ("Today is the 28th")
ElseIf thirtieth = dateToday Then
    MsgBox ("Today is the 30th")
Else
    MsgBox ("You do not need to do anything yet")
End If
```

It is going straight to the end and produces the last message box.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules to be able to quickly eradicate such errors in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Today` is a worksheet function, not a VBA function - you want `Date`:

```
dateToday = Date
```

then you actually want to test against `Day(dateToday)` not just `dateToday`

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you start using `Option Explicit` too - that would have alerted you to this problem. :)